# How to import .NET libraries into project? (Specifically the Amazon API libraries for Amazon MWS)

Tags: api, amazon-web-services

I'm relatively new when it comes to working with .NET and how it works with libraries. I'm trying to use the Amazon MWS libraries for a project but can't figure out how to configure them properly. Any advice for a newbie?

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't realize there were Amazon MWS libraries! I've been hand-coding all my XML requests. Please tell me where I can find them!

Comment: @Mark Richman Ok, your comment is old as sin, I know, but here is what I found for future searchers: https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/orders/orders/v20110101/cSharp.html  I haven't even unzipped it yet, but it was difficult to find, so maybe this can help someone.

Comment: LOL thanks. I've had it up and running for over a year now :)

Answer (score 0):

If what you're missing is a reference to the library, then all you have to do is a right click on the project in the right-pane, and choose "add reference".

Comment: It's more that I need to know how to import all of the Amazon API libraries. Any ideas?

Comment: Add all of the dlls to your references?